# Create function for indirect reference to JSON path and value

Tags: python

I want to use a configuration JSON to tell any function where to get the data from source data JSON.

Example of 3 values I want to add to an array mapped to `value`:

```
data = {
    "value1" : "Hello",
    "value2" : "World",
    "object" : {
        "value3" : "Great"
    }
}
```

For this most basic example, I want to create the following using configuration:

```
example = {
    "example_array" : [
        {"value" : "Hello"},
        {"value" : "World"},
        {"value" : "Great"}
]}
```

What I would prefer is to use a config file which has this:

```
{
    "paths" : [
        {
            "source" : "data",
            "origin_path" : "",
            "origin_value" : "['value1']"
        },
        {
            "source" : "data",
            "origin_path" : "",
            "origin_value" : "['value2']"
        },
        {
            "source" : "data",
            "origin_path" : "['object']",
            "origin_value" : "['value1']"
        }
    ]
}
```

If I could create a function like `set_mapping(destination, source, path, value)` then I want to loop through the paths rows with something like this:

```
for x in origin['paths']:
    origin_data = setmapping(
                value,
                config['paths'][x]['source'],
                config['paths'][x]['origin_path'],
                config['paths'][x]['origin_value']
                )
    example['example_array'].append using origin_data
```

**Original Question**

I want to know if I can control data paths from a configuraiton file so I can process a list of transformations in a loop rather than code for each. In Excel, I would call this an INDIRECT reference to a value used to make up a part of a function, in Python, I can't find out how to do it.

Here's a manual example of what I want to do:

```
print(data['liability_asset']['acceptance']['contractors_and_subcontractors']['contractors_and_subcontractors_engaged'])
```

What I want to be able to do is this instead is maybe have a data path function. I imagine the function to have a definition which is like `data_path(source, path, value)` but that's as far as I got.

```
for x in config['paths]:
    print(data(data_path(['config']['paths'][x]['source'],['config']['paths'][x]['origin_path'], data_path(['config']['paths'][x]['origin_value']
```

Here's an extract from the horrible verbose, nested origin data I need to transform from:

```
data = {
          "liability_asset": {
              "acceptance" : {
                  "contractors_and_subcontractors" : {
                      "contractors_and_subcontractors_engaged" : "YES"
                      }
                  }
              }
       }
```

Here's the config file I intend to use for starters:

```
config = {
    "paths" : [
            {
                 "source" : "data",
                 "origin_path" : "['liability_asset']['acceptance']['contractors_and_subcontractors']",
                 "origin_value" : "['contractors_and_subcontractors_engaged']"
            }

        ]
    }
```

In addition, if there's a way for the script to allow the config to support `.` as separator of a path rather than `['']` each time, that would make the management of the config file much easier.

Expected result from both is `YES`

Comment: Your question is unclear. The lines of code and data are too long to be readable for one thing. And your example usage of this `data_path()` function is incomplete. Can you  describe better what it does and provide a [mre] of using it? Perhaps using slightly less horribly verbose example data.

Comment: thanks @martineau - apologies, its my third attempt describing the problem and giving an indication of how far I got trying to solve it myself before reaching out. I want to use a DICT to define the configuration of data mapping from origin to destination payloads. In order to do this, I need to discover how to do something like print(data_path) where the data_path is a list of JSON paths. I tried to keep it basic by using print as my example use of it. So, print would use a function which reads `config` which tells print to get what to print from `data` using the dict name, path and value.

Comment: I'll edit and add simple example at the top

Comment: Why not make the config file something like: `config = json.loads('{"paths": [{"source": "data", "origin_path": ["liability_asset", "acceptance", "contractors_and_subcontractors"], "origin_value": ["contractors_and_subcontractors_engaged"]}]}')`? You can iterate through those lists as needed in code.

Comment: @martineau I hope the new question is clearer :) Thanks

Comment: @BeRT2me thanks for this, not entirely sure how I would use it though. I would need to reference config from any mapping function performed to pick up the path and source. Thanks

Comment: @MattLightbourn I've given some examples of how they'd be used in my answer~

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

all_data = {}

# mock config file, in reality you'd load it.
config = """{
    "paths" : [
        {
            "source" : "data",
            "origin_path" : [],
            "origin_value" : "value1"
        },
        {
            "source" : "data",
            "origin_path" : [],
            "origin_value" : "value2"
        },
        {
            "source" : "data",
            "origin_path" : ["object"],
            "origin_value" : "value3"
        }
    ]
}
"""
config = json.loads(config)

# Load all of your possible data sources into a dictionary.
# If you already had a 'data' variable, this could just be 
# all_data['data'] = data

all_data['data'] = {
    "value1" : "Hello",
    "value2" : "World",
    "object" : {
        "value3" : "Great"
    }
}


def get_data_via_config(config_file:dict, sources:dict) -> dict:
    # For each given path, goes to the origin_path and adds the 
    # value of each origin_value to the output dict, by name.
    output = {}
    for path in config_file['paths']:
        source = sources[path['source']]
        for o_path in path['origin_path']:
            source = source[o_path]
        # You can modify this next line and make output a list if desired.
        output[path['origin_value']] = source[path['origin_value']]
    return output


example = get_data_via_config(config, all_data)
print(example)
```

Output:

```
{'value1': 'Hello', 'value2': 'World', 'value3': 'Great'}
```

It works just fine for your more complicated example as well:

```
all_data['data_adv'] = {
          "liability_asset": {
              "acceptance" : {
                  "contractors_and_subcontractors" : {
                      "contractors_and_subcontractors_engaged" : "YES"
                      }
                  }
              }
       }

config2 = """{
    "paths" : [
            {
                 "source" : "data_adv",
                 "origin_path" : ["liability_asset", "acceptance", "contractors_and_subcontractors"],
                 "origin_value" : "contractors_and_subcontractors_engaged"
            }

        ]
    }
"""
config2 = json.loads(config2)

example2 = get_data_via_config(config2, all_data)
print(example2)
```

Output:

```
{'contractors_and_subcontractors_engaged': 'YES'}
```

Comment: thank you tons, I haven't completely gone through this yet but at first glance it looks exactly what I needed. It was a very simple set of examples but using what you have shown here, I can build it out to do much more also. Much appreciated

Comment: the only thing I note here is the values being shown here are named as they were in the origin. whereas, I want to give the values a new key. In my output example, all 3 have `value` as their name rather than `value1`, `value2` and `value 3`. How would you extend this so that I am using the config to set a value to a name I am creating?

Comment: I have the location noted in my answer, but you could just change output to a list, and do `output.append({'value': source[path['origin_value']]})` instead.

Comment: But yes, I'd encourage you to run the function a bunch of times and print `path`, `o_path` `source`, etc. at various steps until you have an idea of what's going on~

Comment: I'll give it a go first thing, thanks

Comment: I added a category which would have a string value not a path to add to the object being appended. `output.append({'value': source[path['origin_value']], 'category' : ['category']})` but instead of giving me the value of `category` from the config, it has treated it like text. Any ideas of how I can include this? thanks

Comment: You have to tell it where it's getting `['category']` from... aka `path['category']` or wherever it's actually located.